# Multiple AND and WHERE IN conditions not calculating as expected

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am getting output I am not expecting for the below code:

```
SELECT '107' as ID, sum([NET-COST]) as SPEND, Month([PCR-PO-Date]) AS MONTH
FROM [raw data]
WHERE [PLI-LOCATION] IN ('60PQA', '60PLM', '80PQ', '88PO')
AND YEAR([PCR-PO-DATE]) = 2018
AND [PLI-ITEM] IN ('2942550', '2946560')
Group By Month([PCR-PO-Date]);
```

The output shows me 12 months, many of them are the "correct" number, but several of them are wrong. I ran a similar query multiple times for different items/locations and the numbers are usually right, but sometimes they are off by a little. Always larger than the correct number. I am almost sure this means the parentheses are wrong, and that is leading the AND statements to not work as intended.

I would like the following calculating to take place:
If the location is in my PLI Location list, AND the year is 2018 AND the item is in my PLI Item list, then give me the net-cost of all the items by month. 95% of the time I am getting the "right" number, but sometimes it's off. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's something with `year()` function, maybe it returns something like isoyear instead of year that in the date

Comment: @Y.K.: `Year(somedate)` returns the calendar year which is also the ISO year.

Comment: `Each week's year is the Gregorian year in which the Thursday falls.` from [ISO_week_date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Relation_with_the_Gregorian_calendar)

Comment: so isoyear from 2017-01-01 = 2016

Comment: @Y.K.: You are mixing up the ISO date format and the ISO 8601 year-week number standard. There are no weeks here but _months_ of a _calendar year_ which is what `Month()` and `Year()` always return.

Comment: Not likely cause of issue but advise not to use reserved words as names for anything. Instead of alias Month, use Mo or Mth or Mon. Also, best to avoid punctuation/special characters in naming convention - underscore is only exception so should really use underscore instead of hyphen.

Comment: Is `[NET-COST]` a floating point?  You might try casting it to money type before the sum -- sometimes floats will seem to not add up correctly because of funky rounding issues.